# hamming - hanning conversion matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, filtering

I have designed HPF for hanning window but when I wanted to do the same with hamming window I got the error "Too many input arguments". The hanning version:

```
 function Hd = hpf_han

Fs = 24000;  

N    = 20;        
Fc   = 10400;   
flag = 'scale';  


win = hann(N+1);% win = hamming(N+1); gave the error "too many arguments"


b  = fir1(N, Fc/(Fs/2), 'high', win, flag, 'h');
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
freqz(Hd)
```

How to fix this error and why am i getting it?

Comment: Maybe you've shadowed the `hamming` function with a variable or a user-defined function? Try `clear hamming`. But that's unlikely if the code is within a function. You code works fine for me, both versions

Comment: I have added clear all at the beginning of the function. Maybe it is about Matlab 2015a. I don't know:(

Comment: I will try the same with older version and come back later

Comment: My test was on R2014b

Comment: fdatool of Matlab giving me the error with hamming window as "too many arguments" even in 2012b. The others works fine.

Comment: Try `open hamming` to see if it Matlab is seeing the original function

Comment: Solved it:) Matlab sees my function, i called 'hamming', instead of the original hamming function.